# Reading email using load runner

Tags: imap, loadrunner, pop3, microfocus

Hi I am trying to fetch email from gmail accout by using load runner. I have tried ,IMAP, POP3 protocol.

Using Vugen 2020

### IMAP Protocol

I used below code:

imap_logon("GmailLogin","URL=imaps://{UserEmailID}:{Password}@imap.gmail.com:993","STARTTLS",LAST);

imap_select("SelectInbox","Mailbox=INBOX",LAST);

getting below error:
Action.c(5): Error (-205597): Failed to receive IMap welcome message from imap.gmail.com:993.

I have used gmail app password and also enabled IMAP setting in gmail.

### POP3 PROTOCOL

```
pop3_logon("Login", "URL=pop3s://{UserEmailID}:{Password}@pop.gmail.com:995","STARTTLS", LAST);
```

getting below error:
Action.c(6): Error (-205685): Failed to establish a secure POP3 session.

Answer (score 0):

"I have used gmail app password and also enabled IMAP setting in gmail."

Please read both the license agreements for Google regarding the use of automation against their services outside of published API interfaces, and the LoadRunner license agreement on the use of their tool against systems you do not own, manage, control or have written permission from those that do have those characteristics.

By my reading you are in violation of both Google and Microfocus end user agreements and should not be supported in your efforts.